# Фильтрация в MixItUp

Tags: javascript

Ребят, кто-нибудь знает как в библиотеке MixItUp сделать определенную кнопку фильтра активной? Там по умолчанию активное значение all, а как перенастроить не знаю.
Вот мой код:

```
    <div class="portfolio__menu">
        <button class="portfolio__menu-btn btn" data-filter=".category- 
        branding">BRANDING</button>
        <button class="portfolio__menu-btn btn" data-filter=".category- 
        photography">PHOTOGRAPHY</button>
        <button class="portfolio__menu-btn btn" data-filter=".category- 
         videodesign">WEB DESIGN</button>
        <button class="portfolio__menu-btn btn" data-filter=".category- 
        appdesign">APP DESIGN</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос блок html-кода с кнопками фильтрации.